# Unknown IP value starting with "for" in PHP

Tags: php, ip

I created statistics for my website where am collecting daily unique views and totals views. In uninque views am collecting all the IPS.

I noticed quite a strange thing. Some entries have IP values like the below

```
for=\"105.6.218.225:32174\"
for=\"[2405:204:c10f:3307::183d:38a4]\"
```

Am getting Ips with php like the below

```
$ipaddress = '';
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $iplist = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']); 
    foreach ($iplist as $ip){
        $ipaddress = $ip;
    }
}else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])){
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
}else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])){
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
}else{
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
return $ipaddress;
```

So what this string means? IS it a robot crawling my website or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RFC 7239 `Forwarded` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7239#section-4) does not follow the expected `X-Forwarded-For` header format. Instead, it follows this format:

```
Forwarded: for=192.0.2.60;proto=http;by=203.0.113.43
```

You would want to take just the `for` key-value pair and strip the `for=` part instead of just taking the full string. For example, you could further the `explode` the string by `=`, check if the first part is `for`, and if so use the second part as the IP.

Comment: This happened in which case cause there are few records with this Ip info @Bytewave?

Comment: More than likely, yes. I'm guessing some of the clients connecting to your site are sending the `Forwarded` header in that non-"standard" format which your code doesn't account for.

Comment: Also in teh above string i gave you there is other stuff like check the second example i provided, which part is the Ip there?

Comment: Again, it's the `Forwarded` header that follows this format, so it's likely in where you check for `$_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']`. You're not exploding anything there, you're just taking the value of `Forwarded`, which has more data than just the IP. See the format I supplied, as well as the RFC I posted.

Comment: Ok i see. Can this be crawlers as well?

Comment: Possibly. It just depends on who's submitting the `Forwarded` header with their requests. Proxies, spiders, spiders behind proxies...

Comment: Aha i see. Any way of knowing exactly? Cause am trying to have accurate data and understand from where teh users are coming.

Comment: That's a very different question. There are good bots and bad bots; with good bots, their user agent strings will usually indicate that they're a bot. With bad bots, they'll fake legitimate traffic.